# Node.js async streams backpressure not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, stream, node-streams

I have two async processes, one that produces data and one data consumes data. They work at different rates, so my idea was to leverage [Node.js streams](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/stream.html) to automatically handle backpressure between one stream and the other. I have tried to arrange a solution extending `stream.Readable` and `stream.Writable` classes, using a different delay in `_read` and `_write` implementations to simulate the different rate in the real world (the readable is faster than the writable in my case) and an async generator as the data source. Both the streams work in object mode and have a `highWaterMark = 2`, so I expected that the readable stream to adapt to the writable stream rate once the buffer is full, but this isn't happening. As shown in the output, readable stream keeps pushing data even if the `highWaterMark` is reached.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import { Readable, Writable } from 'stream';

const sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function* asyncGenerator() {
    let i = 0;

    while (i++ < 10) {
        yield { data: i };
    }
}

class TestReadable extends Readable {
    public delay: number;
    private _tag = '[Readable]';
    private _generator = asyncGenerator();

    constructor(delay: number) {
        super({
            objectMode: true,
            highWaterMark: 2,
        });

        this.delay = delay;
    }

    async _read(size: number) {
        while (true) {
            await sleep(this.delay);
            const { value, done } = await this._generator.next();
            const bufferFull = this.push(value);
            console.log(this._tag, `Pushed ${JSON.stringify(value)}`, this.readableLength);

            if (done) {
                this.push(null);
                break;
            }

            if (bufferFull) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

class TestWritable extends Writable {
    public delay: number;
    private _tag = '[Writable]';

    constructor(delay: number) {
        super({
            objectMode: true,
            highWaterMark: 2,
        });

        this.delay = delay;
    }

    async _write(chunk: any, encoding: BufferEncoding, callback: (error?: (Error | null)) => void) {
        await sleep(this.delay);
        console.log(this._tag, `Received ${JSON.stringify(chunk)}`);
        callback();
    }
}

(async() => {
    const readable = new TestReadable(1000);
    const writable = new TestWritable(3000);

    readable.pipe(writable);
})();
```

```
[Readable] Pushed {"data":1} 0
[Readable] Pushed {"data":2} 0
[Readable] Pushed {"data":3} 1
[Writable] Received {"data":1}
[Readable] Pushed {"data":4} 2
[Readable] Pushed {"data":5} 3
[Readable] Pushed {"data":6} 4
[Writable] Received {"data":2}
[Readable] Pushed {"data":7} 3
[Readable] Pushed {"data":8} 4
[Readable] Pushed {"data":9} 5
[Writable] Received {"data":3}
[Readable] Pushed {"data":10} 6
[Readable] Pushed undefined 7
[Writable] Received {"data":4}
[Writable] Received {"data":5}
[Writable] Received {"data":6}
[Writable] Received {"data":7}
[Writable] Received {"data":8}
[Writable] Received {"data":9}
[Writable] Received {"data":10}
[Writable] Received undefined

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I'd suggest you load up the debugger and trace through what happens when you call `this.push()` so you can see exactly what logic it is applying that causes you to exceed the high water mark.  The streams code that gets called when you call `this.push()` is this `readAddChunk()` function.  The code for that is [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1af661908f765f63a8653a6ab272b1ade118f300/lib/internal/streams/readable.js#L242). As there are lots of `if` blocks in that code, it's hard to just read the code and see what path it's taking and why.  Easier to just trace through in the debugger.

Comment: I still don't know why the flow control isn't working properly, but step one is your `bufferFull` variable is backwards.  It should be `const bufferFull = !this.push(value);` because `this.push(value)` returns `false` when the buffer is full.  That alone doesn't solve the issue with the readable exceeding the `highWaterMark` so there must be something else going on here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

In an implementation of `_read()`, you can't do this sequence of events without some undesirable consequences:

```
Asynchronous wait
stream.push(data)
Asynchronous wait
stream.push(data)
```

As soon as you return control back to the event loop after calling `stream.push(data)`, the stream assumes your `_read()` operation is done and will call it again immediately if the buffer isn't full.  The caller has no way to know that your first `_read()` operation is still gathering more data and will still do more `.push()` operations.  Thus is the contract/API for `._read()`.

So as soon as you call `stream.push()` and return control back to the event loop, your processing from that call to `_read()` should be done.

You absolutely can do this in `_read()`:

```
Asynchronous wait
stream.push(data)
```

Or even this:

```
Asynchronous wait
stream.push(data)
stream.push(data)
stream.push(data)
```

Just not this (which is what you were doing):

```
Asynchronous wait
stream.push(data)
Asynchronous wait
stream.push(data)
```

**Long Explanation**

The problem is caused by an intersection of how streams work and how your code is written.  Too summarize, the issue is that you're calling `.push()` multiple times after asynchronous waits for each in the same `_read()`.

That isn't how the caller of `_read()` expects things to work.  You are certainly allowed to go do some asynchronous operation and then call `.push()` one or more times in the same event cycle.  But, things get messed up if you call `.push()` and then return control back to the event loop and then, on some later tick of the event loop, call `.push()` again from the same `_read()` call.  And, that's what your code is doing.

The design of `_read()` is such that you can take as much time as you want to call `.push()`, but as soon as you call `.push()` and return control back to the event loop, the stream sees that there's room in the stream buffer and you've already called `.push()` (so you must be done) so it calls `_read()` again.  But, your previous `_read()` wasn't done yet.  So, now you  have multiple `_read()` loops running at the same time which surprisingly doesn't blow up, but ends up reading too much data and forces the buffer to grow larger than the highWaterMark because the bookkeeping around that assumes that once a call to `_read()` has called `.push()` and returned control back to the event loop, it must be done.  But, yours wasn't done.  There is no other way to communicate that your call to `_read()` isn't done yet.

There are multiple different types of fixes.

1. You can `this.pause()` until your `_read()` is really done and then `this.resume()`.  That does fix the issue, but may have some other side effects on the processing of the stream.
2. You can just read one object at a time and thus one `.push()` per `_read()`.  As soon as you call the `.push()` and return control back, the stream will just call `_read()` again.
3. You can buffer the objects you are collecting and then `.push()` them all into the stream in one synchronous loop.

#2 would be the simplest to implement and in your implementation where you only get one object at a time anyway (always a delay between objects being available), it wouldn't have any downside to performance.

This is an implementation below (in plain Javascript) of option #3 that uses local buffering, but all three fix options work.

```
import { Readable, Writable } from 'stream';

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function* asyncGenerator() {
    let i = 0;

    while (i++ < 10) {
        yield { data: i };
    }
}

class TestReadable extends Readable {

    constructor(delay) {
        super({
            objectMode: true,
            highWaterMark: 2,
        });

        this.delay = delay;
        this._tag = '[Readable]';
        this._generator = asyncGenerator();
    }

    async _read(size) {
        console.log(this._tag, `Starting read(${size})`);
        let readCnt = size;
        const buffer = [];
        while (readCnt > 0) {
            await sleep(this.delay);
            const { value, done } = await this._generator.next();
            if (done) {
                this.push(null);
                break;
            }

            buffer.push(value);
            --readCnt;
        }
        for (let value of buffer) {
            const bufferFull = !this.push(value);
            console.log(this._tag, `Pushed ${JSON.stringify(value)}, length = ${this._readableState.length}, full = ${bufferFull}`);
        }
        console.log(this._tag, `Ending read()`);
    }
}

class TestWritable extends Writable {

    constructor(delay) {
        super({
            objectMode: true,
            highWaterMark: 2,
        });

        this.delay = delay;
        this._tag = '[Writable]';
    }

    async _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        await sleep(this.delay);
        console.log(this._tag, `Received ${JSON.stringify(chunk)}`);
        callback();
    }
}

(async () => {
    const readable = new TestReadable(1000);
    const writable = new TestWritable(3000);

    readable.pipe(writable);
})();
```

Other fixes/changes to the code:

1. Your `bufferFull` logic was backwards.  `this.push()` returns `true` when there's more room in the buffer, not when it's full.  Because my modified code pays attention to the size argument in `_read(size)`, my code doesn't use that value any more.
2. I've implemented controls to respect the `size` argument passed to `_read()` and not read or push more than that.
3. When `done` is true in the call to `await this._generator.next();`, there is no `value`, but you were still pushing that `undefined` value and then later pushing `null`.  The `value` when `done` is `true` is whatever the generator returns at the end.  Your generator does not have a final return value and thus does not have a final value when `done === true`.

---

Here's an implementation of option #2 (reading one object at a time):

```
async _read(size) {
    console.log(this._tag, `Starting read(${size})`);
    await sleep(this.delay);
    const { value, done } = await this._generator.next();
    if (done) {
        console.log(this._tag, 'End of read data');
        this.push(null);
    } else {
        this.push(value);
        console.log(this._tag, `Pushed ${JSON.stringify(value)}, length = ${this._readableState.length}`);
    }
    console.log(this._tag, `Ending read()`);
}
```

You might think this is inefficient to be just pushing one object per call, but it actually isn't.  Because as soon as you push an object and there's more room in the buffer, the stream will immediately schedule a check (for the next tick of the event loop) to call `_read()` again.  So, your `while` loop inside the function has just been replaced by a little logic right in the caller that will just call `_read()` again.  Not much difference.

And, this implementation is by far the simplest of the three solutions I've outlined.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for taking the time to dive deep in this, I have found the exact same things. Indeed I was using the `bufferFull` variable in the opposite way and also the placement for the `done` check was wrong (causing pushing undefined on the buffer). Even with this fixes the buffer is still filled beyond the water mark limit as you have described very clearly. I think that getting rid of the while loop inside `_read` is the best option, `Keep It Simple Stupid` has its merits after all ;-)

Comment: Testing option #2: it seems the buffer is still over filled at the beginning, but after that backpressure seems to work as expected. I can live with that, just wondering why it happens (see output in my updated answer).

Comment: @revy - I don't see where it's ever overfilled.  The highest length value your output shows is 2 which is the highWaterMark - exactly as it should be.

Comment: I see that it pushes 3 objects in the buffer at the beginning. I thought that an `highWaterMark = 2` means maximum 2 objects in the buffer (before the threshold is reached).

Comment: @revy - You see it push 3 objects, but after the third push, the `readableLength` is still only 2.  That's because the first object has been already handed off to the writestream - it just hasn't fully processed it yet to call `_write()` (that's probably happening on the next tick where you immediately see the log for the write).  It called `_read()` the third time because the buffer wasn't full any more.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by `jfriend00`, here is a modified version without using the while loop inside `_read`. There is still an overfill of the readable buffer at the beginning (not sure why) but after that it seems the backpressure is handled correctly:

```
import { Readable, Writable } from 'stream';

const sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function* asyncGenerator() {
    let i = 0;

    while (i++ < 10) {
        yield { data: i };
    }
}

class TestReadable extends Readable {
    public delay: number;
    private _tag = '[Readable]';
    private _generator = asyncGenerator();

    constructor(delay: number) {
        super({
            objectMode: true,
            highWaterMark: 2,
        });

        this.delay = delay;
    }

    async _read(size: number) {
        await sleep(this.delay);
        const { value, done } = await this._generator.next();

        if (done) {
            return this.push(null);
        }

        const bufferFull = !this.push(value);
        console.log(this._tag, `Pushed ${JSON.stringify(value)}`, this.readableLength, bufferFull);
    }
}

class TestWritable extends Writable {
    public delay: number;
    private _tag = '[Writable]';

    constructor(delay: number) {
        super({
            objectMode: true,
            highWaterMark: 2,
        });

        this.delay = delay;
    }

    async _write(chunk: any, encoding: BufferEncoding, callback: (error?: (Error | null)) => void) {
        await sleep(this.delay);
        console.log(this._tag, `Received ${JSON.stringify(chunk)}`);
        callback();
    }
}

(async() => {
    const readable = new TestReadable(1000);
    const writable = new TestWritable(3000);

    readable.pipe(writable);
})();
```

```
[Readable] Pushed {"data":1} 0 false
[Readable] Pushed {"data":2} 0 false
[Readable] Pushed {"data":3} 1 false
[Writable] Received {"data":1}
[Readable] Pushed {"data":4} 2 true
[Writable] Received {"data":2}
[Readable] Pushed {"data":5} 1 false
[Readable] Pushed {"data":6} 2 true
[Writable] Received {"data":3}
[Writable] Received {"data":4}
[Readable] Pushed {"data":7} 1 false
[Readable] Pushed {"data":8} 2 true
[Writable] Received {"data":5}
[Writable] Received {"data":6}
[Readable] Pushed {"data":9} 1 false
[Readable] Pushed {"data":10} 2 true
[Writable] Received {"data":7}
[Writable] Received {"data":8}
[Writable] Received {"data":9}
[Writable] Received {"data":10}

Process finished with exit code 0
```